# Targeting an img that prompts a confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, title

So what I am looking to do is to pull info from a dynamically added `<img>` on mouse click.
It always comes back as undefined.... my code:

```
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    var objectElem = x[i];
     var a = (objectElem.getElementsByTagName("source")[0].textContent),
         b = (objectElem.getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].textContent),
         c = (objectElem.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent),
          num = (objectElem.getElementsByTagName("vote")[0].textContent), 
         par = '<img class="item" href="#" ondblclick="confirmed()" src="'+ a +'" title="' +b+ ' - '+ c+ '" />';
     console.log(par);
     document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += par;
}

function confirmed() {
    targ = (this.title);
    console.log(targ);

    var bools = confirm("Is This Your choice?");
    if(bools == true){
        y=1;
        adds = (++y)
        tote = (num+adds)
        txt=(targ);

    }else{
     txt = "You hit cancel";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;    
}
```

Not sure why, appreciate your help!

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: @j08691 Maybe they don't mind a jQuery solution?  I see no problem with leaving the jQuery tag.

Comment: @puppies_pidgeons Don't concatenate data into HTML.  You risk creating invalid HTML, and potentially open yourself up to injection problems.  Set the attributes on elements with `element.setAttribute()`.  Also, I suggest setting handlers for events programmatically rather than with attributes.

Comment: 'artist' and 'vote' are not valid tag names. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: What is the `x` variable in that for loop?

Comment: @technophobia its:    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("test.xml"),
    testObj = xmlDoc,
    x = testObj.getElementsByTagName("song");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're open to a jQuery solution, have a look at the following snippet while paying attention to the notes:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {

    // Init images (note: This should preferably be done server side if you're parsing xml)
    for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        var a = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics/album-" + i,
            b = "Artist_" + i ,
            c = "Title_" + i,
            num = i,
            par = '<img class="item" href="#" src="'+ a +'" title="'+ b +' - '+ c +'" data-num="'+ i +'" />';
        console.log(par);

        document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += par;
    }

    // Tip: Double Click binding to the img with 'item' class (better than having it inline on the tag)
    $("body").on("dblclick", "img.item", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // not really needed in this case since the default double click on an image does nothing by default, but good to know you can prevent default actions

        var $img = $(this);

        confirmed($img);
    });


    // Important: Notice that we're passing the trigger element (in this case it's the image) to the confirmed function.

    function confirmed($img) {
        var targ = $img.attr("title");
        console.log(targ);

        var confirmation = confirm("Is '" + targ + "' your choice?");
        if (confirmation) {
            y=1;
            adds = (++y)
            tote = (num+adds)
            txt=(targ);

        } else {
            txt = "You hit cancel";
        }

        // $("#demo").html(text) <-- jquery way
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;  
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

<kbd>**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rEVrL/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that set it up perfectly!

Comment: Actually having an issue still, I realise why, just dont know a way to get around it: the .js I attached encloses the imgs in a div tag without the title property, I need to find a way to target the inner tag on each: it displays: <div class="item " style="display: block; left: 1451px; top: 251px; height: 125px; width: 83px; font-size: 25%; z-index: 32761; visibility: visible;"><canvas class="content portray" href="#" ondblclick="confirmed()" src="imgs/download.jpeg" title="MONO - MONO" origproportion="1" width="335" height="502"></canvas><div class="caption">MONO - MONO</div></div>

Comment: I added a comment above, what do ya think?

Comment: Using jQuery, you can travel down the DOM using `.find()` or `.children()` - here's a reference that might help http://api.jquery.com/find/